# ¿Cómo comprobar la captura de pantalla?

Tags: java, android

El [Snapchat](https://www.snapchat.com/) posee una funcionalidad que es notificar al usuario cada vez que alguien, otro usuario cualquiera, toma una captura de pantalla de sus historias.

En principio pensé en la posibilidad de comprobar si el usuario presionó <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd>, pero nada garantiza que el screenshot será guardado, pues puede que no haya suficiente memoria para guardar. Además, creo que cada dispositivo puede cambiar la forma de cómo capturar la pantalla, sin contar que hay otras aplicaciones que facilitan este proceso.

Otra forma sería comprobar si ha habido algún cambio de directorio Capturas de pantalla, usando la clase `FileObserver`, pero tampoco hay garantías que en todos los dispositivos ese path será el mismo.

**¿Cómo puedo comprobar si el usuario tomó una captura de pantalla en el momento del uso de la aplicación?**

Comment: Me he estado informando un poco y no hay unos métodos 100% fiables de ello, pero te recomiendo mirar esta [página](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2geaqv/any_idea_how_snapchat_for_android_does_screenshot/) donde discuten sobre el tema y exponen varios trucos para ello.

Comment: Hay un proyecto en github que parece detectarlo, pero no estoy seguro: https://github.com/jd-alexander/Snapper

Comment: no se si es que comentas que las clases que incluye android para controlar el clipboar carecen de informacion para ver le tamaño de los contenidos, en teoria deberian de dar algun error cuando no quepa http://www.androhub.com/android-clipboard-tutorial/ ahora creo que deberias de estudiar mas esa clase y si quieres saber cuando hay algo en el clipboard, lo dificil seria saber si pertenece a la aplicacion, a menos de que pudieras marcar los contenidos del clipboard o ver la manera de administrarlos desde tu aplicacion propia.

Comment: Aquí tienes una libreria ShotWatch que sirve para detectar y un ejemplo de integración
https://medium.com/@abangfadli/shotwatch-android-screenshot-detector-library-6a75d7242109

Comment: [Mira esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9822607/5587982)  y también las otras. Enfocan una solución desde otra perspectiva.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Como bien mencionas en tu pregunta al usar *`FileObserver` No hay garantías que en todos los dispositivos ese path será el mismo.*

La API de Android no tiene una ruta fija para capturas de pantalla, pero

```
File pix = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File screenshots = new File(pix, "Screenshots");
```

Podría funcionar. Eso es lo que ICS usa como ruta.

Por lo tanto lo que se me ocurre que puede hacer entonces es crear una lista de rutas para cada dispositivo y unirlas con [Build](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build).

---

Al usar [FileObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver), solo monitoree el evento de creación de archivo en el directorio de captura de pantalla.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        + File.separator + Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
        + File.separator + "Screenshots" + File.separator;
Log.d(TAG, path);

FileObserver fileObserver = new FileObserver(path, FileObserver.CREATE) {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
        Log.d(TAG, event + " " + path);
    }
};

fileObserver.startWatching();
```

No olvide declarar los permisos correspondientes para acceder al contenido en la tarjeta SD.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Otra solución para detectar la captura de pantalla es usar `ContentObserver`, porque habrá un registro insertado en la base de datos multimedia del sistema después de la captura de pantalla. Lo siguiente es el fragmento de código que se usa para monitorear el evento `ContentObserver`. Al usar `ContentObserver`, no es necesario declarar los permisos `write`/`read` `external storage`, pero debe hacer algunos filtros en el nombre del archivo para asegurarse de que sea un evento de captura de pantalla.

```
HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("content_observer");
    handlerThread.start();
    final Handler handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper()) {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    };

    getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            true,
            new ContentObserver(handler) {
                @Override
                public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "deliverSelfNotifications");
                    return super.deliverSelfNotifications();
                }

                @Override
                public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
                    super.onChange(selfChange);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onChange " + uri.toString());
                    if (uri.toString().matches(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString() + "/[0-9]+")) {

                        Cursor cursor = null;
                        try {
                            cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] {
                                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
                            }, null, null, null);
                            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                final String fileName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                                final String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
                                // TODO: aplicar filtro en el nombre del archivo para asegurarse de que sea un evento de captura de pantalla
                                Log.d(TAG, "screen shot added " + fileName + " " + path);
                            }
                        } finally {
                            if (cursor != null)  {
                                cursor.close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    super.onChange(selfChange, uri);
                }
            }
    );
```

Si usa este método, debe solicitar `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` después de la versión de `Android M`, de lo contrario arrojará `SecurityException`. Para obtener más información sobre: [cómo solicitar permiso de tiempo de ejecución, consulte aquí](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting).

Sin embargo esto tiene un problema que cuando el observador de contenido haya detectado la imagen de la cámara (debería ser solo una captura de pantalla).

Para solucionar esto:

**ScreenshotDetectionDelegate.java**

```
public class ScreenshotDetectionDelegate {
    private WeakReference<Activity> activityWeakReference;
    private ScreenshotDetectionListener listener;

    public ScreenshotDetectionDelegate(Activity activityWeakReference, ScreenshotDetectionListener listener) {
        this.activityWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(activityWeakReference);
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void startScreenshotDetection() {
        activityWeakReference.get()
                .getContentResolver()
                .registerContentObserver(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, true, contentObserver);
    }

    public void stopScreenshotDetection() {
        activityWeakReference.get().getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(contentObserver);
    }

    private ContentObserver contentObserver = new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
        @Override
        public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
            return super.deliverSelfNotifications();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            super.onChange(selfChange);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
            super.onChange(selfChange, uri);
            if (isReadExternalStoragePermissionGranted()) {
                String path = getFilePathFromContentResolver(activityWeakReference.get(), uri);
                if (isScreenshotPath(path)) {
                    onScreenCaptured(path);
                }
            } else {
                onScreenCapturedWithDeniedPermission();
            }
        }
    };

    private void onScreenCaptured(String path) {
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onScreenCaptured(path);
        }
    }

    private void onScreenCapturedWithDeniedPermission() {
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onScreenCapturedWithDeniedPermission();
        }
    }

    private boolean isScreenshotPath(String path) {
        return path != null && path.toLowerCase().contains("screenshots");
    }

    private String getFilePathFromContentResolver(Context context, Uri uri) {
        try {
            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
            }, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
                cursor.close();
                return path;
            }
        } catch (IllegalStateException ignored) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    private boolean isReadExternalStoragePermissionGranted() {
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activityWeakReference.get(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    public interface ScreenshotDetectionListener {
        void onScreenCaptured(String path);

        void onScreenCapturedWithDeniedPermission();
    }
}
```

**ScreenshotDetectionActivity.java**

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

public abstract class ScreenshotDetectionActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ScreenshotDetectionDelegate.ScreenshotDetectionListener {
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION = 3009;

    private ScreenshotDetectionDelegate screenshotDetectionDelegate = new ScreenshotDetectionDelegate(this, this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        checkReadExternalStoragePermission();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        screenshotDetectionDelegate.startScreenshotDetection();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        screenshotDetectionDelegate.stopScreenshotDetection();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                    showReadExternalStoragePermissionDeniedMessage();
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScreenCaptured(String path) {
        // Hacer algo cuando se capturó la pantalla
    }

    @Override
    public void onScreenCapturedWithDeniedPermission() {
        // Hacer algo cuando se capturó la pantalla, pero se ha denegado el permiso de lectura de almacenamiento externo
    }

    private void checkReadExternalStoragePermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestReadExternalStoragePermission();
        }
    }

    private void requestReadExternalStoragePermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION);
    }

    private void showReadExternalStoragePermissionDeniedMessage() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "El permiso de lectura de lectura externa ha denegado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ScreenshotDetectionActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScreenCaptured(String path) {
        Toast.make(this, path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onScreenCapturedWithDeniedPermission() {
        Toast.make(this, "Por favor, conceda permiso de lectura de lectura externa para la detección de captura de pantalla", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Este código funciona, pero tiene problemas con algunos dispositivos por ejemplo:
Android 6.0 en Nexus 7 da content://media/external/images/media como uri en onChange, que no se puede resolver correctamente en la ruta del archivo.

Si bien la respuesta, no responde a todas las necesidades, pero puede ser una base de empuje para obtener otras ideas, espero le sirva. Saludos!

> Puede encontrar más información en la pregunta original, Fuente SO:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29621903/detect-only-screenshot-with-fileobserver-android